# custom ant build and JavaFX

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javafx-8

with your regular netbeans javaFX project the developer is capable of doing the following
 -make a javaFX jar file
 -make a html with javaFX on browser on it
 -make a jnlp webstart

i want to achieve the same output with ant build (inside netbeans IDE), but so far my success is limited to the javaFX jar file only, i'd want to make the html file and jnlp with ant as well

i am using netbeans 8.0.2, i have a standard java library (non-javaFX) project, this project contains a single backend and two frontends SWING and javaFX, with ant build script i am successful in producing two separate and self contained jar files which is dssSWING.jar and dssJavaFX.jar, each capable of self extracting the database inside of them and having the third party dependencies embedded on each of the as well, here is the ant code i use to produce both

---

```
<!--this build target is meant for building the AJAX SWING (web version) and the Desktop version-->    
<target name="_desktop_SWING_RedistributableSingleJarFile">
    <jar destfile="${basedir}/dss.jar">                    
        <zipgroupfileset dir="protected/lib" includes="h2-1.4.182.jar"/>               
        <zipgroupfileset dir="protected/lib" includes="commons-csv-1.0.jar"/>      
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/build/classes">
            <exclude name=".netbeans_automatic_build"/> 
            <exclude name=".netbeans_update_resources"/> 
            <exclude name="mobileView/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="protected/data" includes="dss.mv.db" />
        <fileset dir="img" >
            <exclude name="Thumbs.db"/>                  
        </fileset> 
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="desktopView.WelcomePage"/>
        </manifest>        
    </jar>
</target>

<!--this build target is meant for building the JavaFX version--> 
<target name="_desktop_javaFX_RedistributableSingleJarFile">
    <jar destfile="${basedir}/dss_javaFX.jar">        
        <zipgroupfileset dir="protected/lib" includes="h2-1.4.182.jar"/>             
        <zipgroupfileset dir="protected/lib" includes="commons-csv-1.0.jar"/>                        
        <zipgroupfileset dir="protected/lib" includes="jfxtras-labs-8.0-r4-20141129.090224-39.jar"/>          
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/build/classes">
            <exclude name=".netbeans_automatic_build"/> 
            <exclude name=".netbeans_update_resources"/> 
            <exclude name="desktopView/**"/>
        </fileset>        
        <fileset dir="protected/data" includes="dss.mv.db" />
        <fileset dir="img" >
            <exclude name="Thumbs.db"/>                  
        </fileset> 
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="mobileView.Main"/>
        </manifest>        
    </jar>
</target>
```

---

please don't tell to make it into javaFX project instead (easy way out), i would like to learn the exact ant script to generate the HTML file embedding on the javaFX jar file as well as the jnlp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR; indeed, i have success producing jnlp and html file, the exact code that does it is, this code outputs java_DSS.jnlp, java_DSS.html and finally to make it work the original javaFX jar file must be on the same directory

---

```
<fx:deploy width="100%" height="100%"
        outdir="web-dist" outfile="java_DSS" 
        offlineAllowed="true">
    <fx:info title="java DSS"/>
    <fx:application refid="java DSS"/>
    <fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}">
           <include name="dss_javaFX.jar"/>
        </fx:fileset>
    </fx:resources>
</fx:deploy>
```

---

end of line my efforts became waste, javaFX webstart or HTML embed needs to be signed in order to be able to run with write/read access to a database, there i available ant code to do the signing but i have no valid 'keyStore' file in order to get it signed, the signing process also does not accept jar files built with `<target>`, it must be built with `<fx:jar>` in order to work, unfortunately `<fx:jar>` does not support embedding of external lib files, you'd have to unzip the libs before you can add them, TLDR

if you want custom ant built javaFX jar,jnlp,html file don't even bother you'd be wasting a lot of time. i wasted 6 hours trying to do that ending with an unsigned output which cannot run on webstart or html embed mode

SOLUTION

what i did was build the ant javaFX jar file, created a new javaFX project and added the javaFX jar file there making the main class of that project a 'launcher' my javaFX jar file, within 5 minutes i have a signed jar,jnlp, and html without having to convert my 'main' project into javaFX project, in a nutshell just make a javaFX 'launcher' project instead of making you own, netbeans will handle all the signing and complicated stuff

Answer (score 1):

[This website](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm) should tell you everything you need to know as far as what's happening under the hood in the ant deployment task, and as such, it also includes links to all the ant tasks and settings you'll need in order to create things like jnlp, etc, etc.

TL;DR, you interact with the ant-javafx.jar, you 'overload' (or whatever you call it in ant world) the fx:deploy task, set some properties, and then magic happens.

If you want to see the nitty gritty of how netbeans handles a .jnlp creation, I uploaded the (most) relevant (3000 line).xml file to pastebin at http://pastebin.com/hRBpMuUG

Hope that helps.. good luck!